# SpringBoot RestClient TraceId

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, trace, rest-client, spring-resttemplate

I switched from RestTemplate to RestClient in my application and since switching I’m unable to get the same TraceId between services. Is anyone else having this same problem?

I tried updating everything as the Spring documentation suggest but no luck. I’m expecting to get the same TraceId when one service calls another.

Comment: That should work out-of-the-box as it uses the same parts as the `RestTemplate` does. Add your configuration (you should have little to non for this to work).